# Realm exception when schema is created - on iOS only

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm, realm-net

This occurs at the first call to `Realm.GetInstance`. Happens only on iOS - while on Android it works fine. The Realm version is 0.77.2.

This is a Xamarin project with MvvmCross and ReactiveUI, but most likely this doesn't matter.

The call to `Realm.GetInstance` happens a bit late - while similar to Android - after MvvmCross is bootstrapped and at least one screen is displayed.

The error is:

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (System.Reflection.Assembly,bool)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3539/f37444ae/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:402 
  at Realms.RealmSchema.<BuildDefaultSchema>m__3 (System.Reflection.Assembly a) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>c__Iterator2`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x00059] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3539/f37444ae/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:423 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[TSource].MoveNext () [0x00062] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3539/f37444ae/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:147 
  at Realms.RealmSchema.CreateSchemaForClasses (IEnumerable`1 classes, Realms.SchemaHandle schemaHandle) [0x00025] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Realms.RealmSchema.BuildDefaultSchema () [0x00071] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].CreateValue () [0x00075] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3539/f37444ae/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/Lazy.cs:437 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3539/f37444ae/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3539/f37444ae/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3539/f37444ae/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3539/f37444ae/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3539/f37444ae/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113
```

Comment: What is `Linker behavior` set to on that iOS build?

Comment: Yes, it is `Don't link`. What's the recommended option? Link all assemblies or SDK assemblies only?

Comment: I thought maybe it is linking out some your classes since it is a `ReflectionTypeLoadException`... it is not the iOS10 Beta Cycle8 from Xamarin is it?

Comment: @SushiHangover: It is. That's what was happening. The don't link option linked out I think all of my `RealmObject`s. If you want you can post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a reflection issue (`ReflectionTypeLoadException`), I would have to assume the 'Xamarin.iOS` linker is removing some classes.

You can manually add the `[Xamarin.iOS.Foundation.Preserve]` attribute to those classes (or members) so they are not linked out as you will *probably* want to set the Linker to Link all or Link Only SDK in your release builds to reduce the final `.ipa` size.

> You can apply this attribute on every member of a type, or on the type itself. If you want to preserve the whole type, you can use the syntax [Preserve (AllMembers = true)] on the type.
>
> Sometimes you want to preserve certain members, but only if the containing type was preserved. In those cases, use [Preserve (Conditional=true)]

Ref: [Preserving Code](https://developer.xamarin.com/Guides/ios/Advanced_Topics/Linker/#Preserving_Code)

Answer (score 1):

We attempt to add a `[Preserve (AllMembers = true)]` attribute automatically to your classes that descend from `RealmObject` so you should not have to manually add them as @SushiHangover suggests.

So it sounds like this is not happening in the Fody weaving step. That might be a bug. It may also be that the way we build our `PreserveAttribute` is not compatible with the one in this version of IOS so is not acting to preserve

I find the naming convention for linking on Xamarin very counter-intuitive. The names make more sense if you substitute the words *Attempt Stripping Unused* for *Link* eg: *Don't Attempt Stripping Unused*

Do you have your own constructors on your `RealmObject` subclasses?

**Yes**

Can you please post the exact IOS and Xamarin Studio versions being used?

*The Xamarin version is 4.1.2.18 and the Xamarin.iOS version is 9.8.2.22. I'm using VS 2015 Update 3, not Xamarin Studio.*

I have added [issue 822](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/822) to track this as a fairly high priority in Realm.

Comment: Yes, having the attribute added automatically would be better. I have a default constructor on that particular `RealmObject` where the issue occurred. The Xamarin version is 4.1.2.18 and the Xamarin.iOS version is 9.8.2.22. I'm using VS 2015 Update 3, not Xamarin Studio.